# h:inputText inside ui:repeater displays wrong value after an ajax update

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, uirepeat

I've got a JSF page with a ui:repeater tag that simply displays a list of strings and some controls to add a string to a list. When adding a string I use ajax to update the repeater tag and have the new string be shown immediately without the page refresh. Here's how my page looks like:

```
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:inputText id="name" value="#{testController.newString}"/>
        <p:commandButton value="Add" actionListener="#{testController.addString}" update="strings" />
    </h:form>       

    <h:panelGroup id="strings">         
        <ui:repeat var="str" value="#{stringModel.strings}" varStatus="stringData">                                                                                                             
            <div>                                       
                <h:outputText value="#{str}" />
                <h:inputText value="#{str}" />
            </div>                                                                                  
        </ui:repeat>
    </h:panelGroup>                              

</h:body>
```

Everything works except the inputText component. After ui-repeater is updated with Ajax is still displays the text from the previous string. For example, assume that initially i have a list with 2 strings, "val1" and "val2". I enter a new string called "val3" and submit the form. List is updated correctly on the server side and the repeater is updated, it now has 3 elements. However, while the h:outputText in the newly added element will correctly show "val3", the inputText will be displayed with "val2" as a value. So i end up with something looking like this:

```
output tag     input tag
val1           val1
val2           val2
val3           val2 (???)
```

The backing beans are very simple:
A view scoped model bean

```
@Component
@Scope("view")
public class StringModel {

    private List<String> strings = Lists.newArrayList("Value 1");

    public List<String> getStrings() {
        return strings;
    }

    public void setStrings(List<String> strings) {
        this.strings = strings;
    }   
}
```

And a request scoped controller bean:

```
@Component
@Scope("request")
public class TestController {

    private String newString;
    @Autowired private StringModel model;

    public void addString() {
        model.getStrings().add(newString);
    }

    public String getNewString() {
        return newString;
    }

    public void setNewString(String newString) {
        this.newString = newString;
    }   

}
```

I did some testing and this actually works the same way for any input component, be that textInput, textArea, etc. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It makes no sense.  You are outputting the exact same #{str} twice.  How could it change?  Can you try printing #{str} a third time see what it gives?

Comment: Problem's not in the number of times I print it out, but rather in how JSF handles input elements inside ui:repeat. I can print it out 10 times and all input components will have wrong value, while output ones won't.

Comment: I could not believe you had pasted the right code.  I asked you to try print a third value since I thought you might see a mistake somewhere.  Apparently you are not the problem but it is this aberrant bug instead...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't tell in detail exactly why it displays the wrong value after update (it'll be that the internal loop index of `<ui:repeat>` is broken — try a newer Mojarra version), but just referencing the string item by index from `varStatus` works. It'll also immediately fix the future problem of being unable to submit the edited string value when you put this list in a form, because the `String` class is immutable and doesn't have a setter.

```xml
<ui:repeat value="#{stringModel.strings}" var="str" varStatus="loop">
    <div>
        <h:outputText value="#{str}" />
        <h:inputText value="#{stringModel.strings[loop.index]}" />
    </div>
</ui:repeat>
```

Comment: Indeed this works. Thanks for pointing this out - i've spent a day on this but it never crossed my mind to try it like that. (as for setting a string, in reality i have an object there, i've just stripped it down to the simplest possible example to illustrate the problem).

Answer (score 2):

EditableValueHolders inside ui:repeat are broken (by design) in the current version o JSF specs. It will not work, there is no way to fix it. Maybe new versions will make ui:repeat a proper component with support for saving states of its children. Maybe not.

If you change ui:repeat to h:dataTable, things should work (if not, then your problem is somewhere else and I was wrong).

Frankly, there is no workaround apart from using repeaters from some other libraries - you should find working repeaters in Tomahawk, Trinidad and many other places. Primefaces, AFAIR, does not have a pure repeater.

Comment: @toto: Seems to me it is a bit by design. There is a certain reluctance surrounding the problem, as if the developers thought that fixing it goes against the JSF architecture (as is in the case of multi-field validation, where I strongly agree with them). The problems with repeater/uiinputare well known for a lot of time (a lot of bugs opened in Mojarra, some are two years and two major releases old), and yet nothing changes.

Comment: Hey, I just wanted to say that this answer was really helpful- it convinced me that I wasn't crazy. Replacing my a4j:repeat (which uses ui:repeat) with a c:forEach solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I also had exactly the same problem before. I solved it by putting the inputText in a form. I also copied your codes and put the `h:inputText` inside a `h:form` and it worked as well.

```
<h:form>
    <ui:repeat value="#{stringModel.strings}" var="str" varStatus="loop">
        <div>
            <h:outputText value="#{str}" />
            <h:inputText value="#{str}" />
        </div>
    </ui:repeat>
</h:form>
```

Comment: The form presentation will work well, but the form submit won't work well (for the very simple reason that the `String` class is immutable and doesn't have a setter method). How to fix that as well, see my answer.